# c++ boost namespacing (and not only) name shortcuts

Tags: c++, boost, shortcut

I am defining a boost multiindex container:

```
namespace bmi = boost::multi_index;
struct DijkstraTriplet {
...
};

typedef multi_index_container <
  DijkstraTriplet,
  bmi::indexed_by<
    bmi::ordered_unique<bmi::member<DijkstraTriplet,size_t,&DijkstraTriplet::linkId> >,
    bmi::ordered_non_unique<bmi::identity<DijkstraTriplet> >
 >
> DijkstraTripletContainer;
```

at some point I am filling it with data and would like to scan one of its indexes. For that purpose I define an iterator:

```
DijkstraTripletContainer::nth_index<0>::type::iterator it;
```

(using an old compiler). This is incredibly long and awkward. To make it shorter and more readable I added those lines:

```
#define dtt0 DijkstraTripletContainer::nth_index<0>::type
#define dtt1 DijkstraTripletContainer::nth_index<1>::type
```

and then used dtt0::iterator (which is elegantly short, but at the same time ugly, because expressed in terms of #defines). Is there a more elegant way to have a shortcut without #defines? I am looking something as elegant as

```
namespace bmi = boost::multi_index;
```

Comments?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
typedef DijkstraTripletContainer::nth_index<0>::type dtt0;
```

Comment: I am wondering how I did not think of it myself. Most probably, because it is a combination of a namespace and a type..